# Вывод дочерних таксономий в иерархическом порядке WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Нужно вывести дочерние таксономии из основной, которые тоже имеют свои дочерние рубрики. wp_list_categories() не подходит, ибо там только списком выводит. А get_term и get_term_children выводят только по 1 уровню вложенности.

Мне в итоге нужно выводить таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каталог оборудования
-Котлы
--Газовые
--Электрические
-Радиаторы
--Стальные панельные
--Стальные

И тд.

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно вывести дочерние таксономии из основной, которые тоже имеют свои
>   дочерние рубрики.

Можно использовать [get_term_children](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/). [Вольный перевод на русский](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_term_children)